# Chemical equation in LaTeX

Tags: equations

I am trying to create an equation in LaTeX using the following code.

```
\delta{$^{66}$}Zn = \Bigg[ \frac{{($^{66}$Zn/ $^{64}$Zn)$_{sample}$}}{{( $^{66}$Zn/ $^{64}$Zn)$_{standard}$}} - 1 \Bigg] \times $1000\textperthousand$
```

When I run TeXWorks, I end up with a bunch of errors. The errors look like

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.11 \delta
           {$^{66}$}Zn = \Bigg[ \frac{{($^{66}$Zn/ $^{64}$Zn)$_{sample}$}}{{...
```

I am trying to reproduced the following figure with the permille symbol at the end of the equation. The `\frac` command does not seem to split the numerator and the denominator as shown in the figure.

[image]

Any help will be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amsmath}
\begin{document}


\delta{$^{66}$}Zn = \Bigg[ \frac{{($^{66}$Zn/ $^{64}$Zn)$_{sample}$}}{{( $^{66}$Zn/ $^{64}$Zn)$_{standard}$}} - 1 \Bigg] \times $1000\textperthousand$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add a full MWE instead of your snippets for can see your preamble and which packages are using you and then can help you?

Comment: Your expression must be set in math mode, thus enclosed in `\[...\]` delimiters or `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question - just a tip: it's usually preferable to make "sample" and "standard" upright, as in Heiko Oberdiek's answer

Comment: Continuing what @Au101 said, do this with `\text{sample}`, etc. Note the currently-bad kerning between the R and D of 'standard'.

Comment: @Steven: I tried using the \[ and \] in math mode. I got the Missing $ error

Comment: Things like `\Bigg` and `\frac` are also math mode only commands.  Thus, I would remove all occurances of `$` from your example, and surround the whole thing in a `\[...\]` structure.  To get "Zn" in non-math mode, one would use `\textrm{Zn}` for example.   The answers that suggest `mhchem` package are probably better still than what I suggest.

Comment: Why are you adding the `perthousand`?

Comment: While all the answers using `mhchem` are technically correct, the `chemmacros` package is newer, and has a number of features that `mhchem` does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `mhchem` package, which eases typesetting chemical reactions/compounds. If the `chemgreek` package is installed, mhchem will load it so as to have `upright` greek letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem, textcomp}

\begin{document}

\[ \ce{\delta^{66} Zn} = \left[ \frac{\bigl(\ce{^{66}Zn}/\ce{^{64}Zn}\bigr)_\text{sample}}{\bigl(\ce{^{66}Zn}/ \ce{^{64}Zn}\bigr)_\text{standard}} - 1 \right] \times 1000\,\text{\textperthousand} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works!!! Thank you so much. I can use the \Large command before the equation and everything is systematically enlarged. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: What does the delta represent in the equation? (I have my doubts that it should be upright here…)

Comment: @clemens: No idea. I'm not a chemist. The `mhchem` doc seems to say Greek letters in chemistry are upright. Anyway, italic Greek letters in maths is not universal: the French use (and possibly the Russian)  is upright Greek letters and uppercase Latin letters.

Comment: I know about the upright letters in chemistry (I wrote `chemgreek`): mostly that's in chemical names. A variable still is a variable and should be italic...

Comment: Not in France, unless it's a lowercase Latin letter. Further more it has the advantage of a less uniform look on the page, easing readability, in my opinion.

Comment: @Bernard I just cite IUPAC recommendations :)

Comment: Sure. I personally have no competence in the domain of chemistry. I just wonder why the package author insists on loading a package for upright Greek letters. Maybe Greek variables have a different degree of variability from Latin variables? :o)

Comment: @Bernard a lot of chemical names contain Greek letters such as alpha-Glucose and it happens that they are used in chemical formulae as well. Some Greek letters have a certain meaning in coordination chemistry, ... The IUPAC recommendation for those cases is upright (they're not variables but are (in a sense) functions)

Answer (score 7):

For example, package `mhchem` can be used to typeset the chemical formulas. The letters of a chemical symbol are usually put upright. The permille sign can be set as `\textperthousand` in text mode (`\text` with package `amsmath` or `amstext` or `\mbox`). The example goes a step further and uses package `siunitx` for setting the number with "unit" permille.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\permille{\text{\textperthousand}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \delta\, \ce{^{66}Zn} =
  \left[
    \frac{\ce{(^{66}Zn/^{64}Zn)_{sample}}}
         {\ce{(^{66}Zn/^{64}Zn)_{standard}}}
    - 1
  \right]
  \times \SI{1000}{\permille}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

How about this? I've used the mhchem package for the Zn. I highely recommend it to simplify any chemical typesetting needs.

[image: big chemical formula]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \delta\thinspace\ce{^{66}Zn} = \Biggl[\frac{(\ce{^{66}Zn}/\ce{^{64}Zn})_{\text{sample}}}{(\ce{^{66}Zn}/\ce{^{64}Zn)}_{\text{standard}}} - 1\Biggr] \times 1000 \text{\textperthousand}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The edited version is almost identical to the other solution. `\text{}` can be used in math mode to type the `\textperthousand`. This symbol isn't available in all font encodings, hence the `fontenc` package.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps partially. Could I possibly replace the % by permille symbol? the \permil and \textperthousand commands do not seem to work with the proposed code.

Comment: I added the \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath,amsmath} and that seems to fix it. However I cannot increase the size of the equation. I used the following code.                                                                                                   \LARGE \delta\thinspace\ce{^{66}Zn} = \Biggl[\frac{(\ce{^{66}Zn}/\ce{^{64}Zn})_{sample}}{(\ce{^{66}Zn}/\ce{^{64}Zn)}_{standard}} - 1\Biggr] \times 1000 \textperthousand

Comment: I am not sure how I can insert codes within comments. I am sorry if the earlier comment looks scrambled

Comment: Use `\`code\``. Note also the bad kerning between R and D in 'standard' in your answer -- use `\text{standard}` (and everywhere else that's properly text) to fix this.

Comment: Excellent this is very helpful. Thanks a lot guys. Lastly, any idea of how I can increase the size of the equation by 50 or 60 % ?