# Per mille symbol in SIunitx

Tags: symbols, siunitx, units

There was a [previous question on the per mille symbol in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123592/per-mille-symbol-in-classicthesis-style). I was wondering if it is available in the *SIunitx* package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you search through  `siunitx` manual?

Comment: Hi! Yes. There is the percent symbol.

Comment: And no "\perthousand" :-(. Unfortunately (in your case) it is not SI units ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [this](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) is the most recent siunitx' manual. Here the word percent appears only five times, and I cannot find permille or similar.
A possible answer can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249454/chemical-equation-in-latex/249457#249457), that is, you can put the following declaration in the preamble

```
\DeclareSIUnit\permille{\text{\textperthousand}}
```

and then use it just as the `\percent` macro of `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{textcomp} % to use \textperthousand                                                     
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\DeclareSIUnit\permille{\text{\textperthousand}}

\begin{document}      
In normal text        
\SI{10}{\permille}    
is the same as        
\SI{1}{\percent}.     

Also in               
\textit{italic        
\SI{10}{\permille}    
is the same as        
\SI{1}{\percent}      
}                     
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add to your answer an example of use of your solution? It doesn't work for me ...

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Looks like the thing to do. However, it doesn't work for me. It should work, as written in the other question I've cited, but I'm using XeLaTeX. Any idea? I've loaded the textcomp package.

Comment: At the moment I have no LaTeX distrubution, so I'm just using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, so the essential part of your answer is, that it works only if you use correct font family ...

Comment: Just for completeness (also not at a pc) have you checked if strange things happen if the context is italic (just because `\text` then behaves differently)

Comment: @daleif, I checked and everything's ok, I think.